# The cat, the echo, and the process substitution

Tags: bash, echo, cat, process-substitution

Basically I am trying to understand the difference between those commands:

```
cat <<< yolo | tee f.txt
echo yolo | tee t.txt
```

And those commands:

```
cat <<< yolo > >(tee f.txt)
echo yolo > >(tee t.txt)
```

The first two commands have the exact same result: "yolo" is printed and the terminal gives back the control after that, which is exactly what I would expect.

> [user@localhost ~]$ cat <<< yolo | tee f.txt
>
> yolo
>
> [user@localhost ~]$ echo yolo | tee t.txt
>
> yolo

But with process substitution, something strange occurs with `echo`.

> [user@localhost ~]$ cat <<< yolo > >(tee f.txt)
>
> yolo
>
> [user@localhost ~]$ echo yolo > >(tee t.txt)
>
> [user@localhost ~]$ yolo

The terminal gives back the control *before* the text is printed out. **Why do I get the control sooner in this case?**

This must have something to do with how processes are opened and how file descriptors are passed between processes, but I am kind of reaching the limits of my knowledge.

If I pipe it to anything else, everything goes back to normal, e.g. `echo yolo > >(tee t.txt) | cat`.

What’s even more strange is that xargs'ing into `echo` works well:

> [user@localhost ~]$ xargs echo <<< yolo > >(tee t.txt)
>
> yolo

But you could say that `xargs` is the main program here, not `echo`.

And if I use an input process substitution with `cat` I have mixed results:

`cat < <(echo yolo) > >(tee t.txt)`

Sometimes it gives me this:

> [user@localhost ~]$ cat < <(echo yolo) > >(tee t.txt)
>
> [user@localhost ~]$ yolo

And sometimes this:

> [user@localhost ~]$ cat < <(echo yolo) > >(tee t.txt)
>
> yolo

So I guess this may have something to do with how fast the system executes the command, which kind of makes it unpredictable.

Does that mean that the output process substitution (e.g. `tee` in this example) runs in the background?

Comment: This seems to be related to the fact `echo` is a built-it and out of all four options there is one `fork()`/`clone()` less, you replace it with `/bin/echo yolo > >(tee t.txt)` and you should get the same behavior as the previous three again. At least that was what I've observed.

Comment: Whether I call `/usr/bin/echo yolo > >(tee t.txt)` or `'echo' yolo > >(tee t.txt)` (with quotes) I get the same result as `echo yolo > >(tee t.txt)`. But if this is performance-related, then calling /usr/bin/echo may be slightly slower/faster depending on the system, causing the issue to appear/disappear on different computers.

Comment: Pro tip: You can synchronize the output of process substitution by pipeing it to another process, that way that another process will not exit until input stream is open and bash will wait on it, so effectively it will wait for process substition. So  `echo yolo >(tee t.txt) | cat` will synchronize the output.

Comment: @KamilCuk yup, and that was one of my suggestions actually ;) but that’s not really an option because in my situation I am interested in the exit code of `echo` and I’d like to avoid playing with PIPESTATUS (and yes I know that `echo` always returns 0, but as you may have guessed I will use another program eventually).

Comment: Why avoid playing with PIPESTATUS? This would work: `{ echo yolo; echo $? > "temporary_tile"; } | tee t.txt; `

Comment: @KamilCuk I don’t like PIPESTATUS because it makes the code harder to read and less easy to maintain e.g. `if echo tolo > >(tee t.txt), then ... fi` vs. `echo yolo | tee t.txt; if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]; then ... fi`

Comment: What about `if echo yolo | tee t.txt; [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]; then` ? I believe doing your own workarounds will be harder to read and less easy to maintain - using `PIPESTATUS` is the established way of handling return values in a chain of pipes.

Comment: @KamilCuk Also, I think that intermediate files should be used as a last resort because of the many dangers of file systems (disk full, write permission, etc.)

Comment: @KamilCuk yup that would work too, but IMO it’s still more ugly than `echo yolo > >(tee t.txt)` YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I think I've found [it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)...

> Process Substitution
>   ... The process `list` is run **asynchronously**, and its input or output appears as a filename...

Once a command (or forked process completes), control is returned to the terminal and next prompt is displayed. I originally suspect `echo` being built-in could have played role, but it really only skewed the timing. I.e. once using `> >(tee t.txt)` when does `tee` get to print to console is not exactly deterministic.

For that matter, try this (for your third example):

```
$ cat <<< yolo > >(sleep 1; tee f.txt)
$ yolo
```

As opposed to:

```
$ { echo yolo; sleep 1 ;} > >(tee t.txt)
yolo
$
```

---

Difference is that `>(list)` process substitution is as mentioned executed asynchronously. Try the former of the two examples, even with a greater value for `sleep` to simulate a long running process. It'll hang around while you keep using your shell (actually even if you terminate it, in which case it gets re-parented, but you'd still see in the process list; side note: *"Commands run as a result of command substitution ignore the keyboard-generated job control signals `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`, and `SIGTSTP`."* -> even loosing terminal won't kill them, unlike asynchronous (`&`) execution example below).

[Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) on the other hand:

> If the pipeline is not executed asynchronously (see Lists), the shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to complete.

Shell does not resume control (next command does not execute) until all commands from the pipeline finished execution.

Try:

```
$ echo yolo |  (sleep 1; tee f.txt)
yolo
$
```

as opposed to (similar to using `>(list)`):

```
echo yolo |  ((sleep 1; tee f.txt) &)
$ yolo
```

(The double sub-shell is not really needed, I've just used it to suppress job control messages in the running shell).

Comment: Interesting, but I don’t quite get why `tee` terminates later. I thought that quitting `cat` or `echo` would close the file descriptor similarly than when using pipes. Otherwise it would mean that processes started by process substitution may try to read from closed pipes (more exactly from very recently closed pipes right after the initiating program exits).

Comment: The chain of events are: `echo` terminates. `echo` closes stdout. `tee` get's notified that input is closed. `tee` terminates. So because we have scheduler, `bash` process can get cpu time before `tee` and `bash` can see that `echo` terminated before `tee` would see that. So this is what you see - `bash` get's enough cpu time to write `$`, while `tee` terminates later, flushes it's stdout and writes `yolo`.

Comment: I think the `echo yolo |  ((sleep 1; tee f.txt) &)` example is very instructive. I can see quite well why this command does give the control back too early, and essentially process substitution is (almost) identical.

Comment: I've added a section to explain the difference. The mechanics of of file/pipe handling are largely similar (in case of `>(list)` it duplicates the handle one more time and it can be accessed through `/dev/fd/` -> points to `/proc/`).